# Select column-wise of a 2d array in ruby

Tags: ruby, multidimensional-array

I have a 2d array `A = [[a1,a2,a3],[b1,b2,b3],[c1,c2,c3]].`
I want to access this array column-wise.
something like that-

```
A[all][0]
-> [a1,b1,c1]
```

How can i do that?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Do as below using [`#transpose`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Array.html#method-i-transpose) method :

```
A.transpose.each do |ary|
   # your code
end
```

As per your comment, I would suggest to use [`Matrix`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.1/libdoc/matrix/rdoc/Matrix.html) class. Once you will create a `Matrix` object, you can access the elements of it, *row wise* or *column wise*.

```
require 'matrix'

A = [['a1','a2','a3'],['b1','b2','b3'],['c1','c2','c3']]

mat = Matrix[ *A ]
mat.column(1).to_a # => ["a2", "b2", "c2"]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.But just from my curiosity is it possible without using transpose method? Is there any symbol to select all index?

Answer (score 9):

An alternative option would be to use to use [Array#map](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Array.html#method-i-map):

```
A = [["a1","a2","a3"],["b1","b2","b3"],["c1","c2","c3"]]
=> [["a1", "a2", "a3"], ["b1", "b2", "b3"], ["c1", "c2", "c3"]]
>> col = 0
=> 0
>> A.map{|a| a[col]}
=> ["a1", "b1", "c1"]
```

Could be rolled into a method as needed.

Comment: Sometimes simplest is best.  The other approaches (including mine) manipulate the entire array when only part of it is needed.

Answer (score 2):

The short answer:

```
A_t = A.tranpose
A_t[0]
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use [Array#transpose](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Array.html#method-i-transpose), but here's an alternative using [Array#zip](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Array.html#method-i-zip):

```
A = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]

A.first.zip(*A[1..-1]).first #=> [1, 4, 7]
```

If, instead,

```
a = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
```

and you didn't mind altering `a`, you could do it this way:

```
a.shift.zip(*a).first #=> [1, 4, 7]
```